# Why won't this Apache modrewrite RewriteRule work?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get Apache mod rewrite to work on my local machine. I'm running OSX with PHP 5 and the Apache mod rewrite module is enabled.

I have a directory called localhost/~Jason/hfh/admin with various PHP includes called based on a $_GET variable. I want to let users type (in theory)

```
localhost/~Jason/hfh/admin/pages
```

and have that URL stay in the address bar, while what gets displayed is

```
localhost/~Jason/hfh/admin/?admin=pages
```

So.

I've created a .htaccess file that sits in the /hfh directory. Inside, I've put this mod rewrite text:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/.]+)/?$ admin/?admin=$1 [L]
```

When I go to the browser and type

```
localhost/~Jason/hfh/admin/pages
```

I get a "Problem loading page" error, and Firefox says, "Oops. Firefox can't load this page for some reason."

Can anyone help me figure this out? I have such a hard time with regex and mod rewrite...

Comment: If mod_rewrite is falling over then there should be something in the error logs - probably in /var/log/apache2/error_log (or at least that's where it is on my Mac).

Comment: Yes this is the line from that error_log: [Sun Nov 29 20:46:29 2009] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Users/Jason/Sites/hfh/admin/pages

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly writing index.php in your RewriteRule.

```
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/.]+)/?$ admin/index.php?admin=$1 [L]
```

You may also find it to be cleaner organization to just move this directive to a .htaccess file in /admin/ itself, thus removing duplication in the rule and making the rule easier to find later.

Comment: I added the index.php (though you shouldn't have to, right?) and still no change. I'll gladly move the rule down into /admin/ if it ever works, but I'd like to get it working first!

Comment: I've had the RewriteBase in there at times, it makes no difference. I had: RewriteBase localhost/~Jason/hfh/

Comment: @Jason Rhodes: The base would be just `/~Jason/hfh/`.

Comment: Thanks. That base didn't make it work, though. Still at a total loss.

Answer (score 0):

So far the answer appears to be: you can't use mod-rewrite on localhost.