# Why won't this mod-rewrite rule work?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a development site on my machine at

```
localhost/~Jason/hfh/admin/?admin=collections
```

My .htaccess file is in the /hfh/admin/ directory. It says:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~Jason/hfh/
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]*)$ index.php?admin=$1
```

But when I go to

```
localhost/~Jason/hfh/admin/collections
```

I get a "page not found" error. Can anyone tell me why?

(This is related to another question at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817455/why-wont-this-apache-modrewrite-rewriterule-work).)

Comment: Are these the only rules you have in the .htaccess?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole .htaccess file right there. I have a blank .htaccess file in the /~Jason/hfh/ directory, too.

Comment: Is there a problem with using mod-rewrite on localhost??

Comment: shouldn't make a difference, as long as mod-rewrite is actually working

Comment: I have a feeling it must have something to do with localhost. That's the only explanation that makes sense. Looking into it.

Comment: Just tested the exact same .htaccess file and directory structure on my webhost server and it worked perfectly. Still not sure why localhost doesn't work, but that's definitely the problem.

Comment: Are you going to "http://localhost/..." or just "localhost/..." as the latter might being treated as a file based url, and thus not touching appache, and therefore not touching mod_rewrite

Comment: sorry, http part of the url is getting swallowed...

Comment: I'm using http just like a real URL for localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short, direct answer for now appears to be: you can't use mod_rewrite on your localhost.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the .htaccess file in /hfh/admin/ make that the base to begin with.

```
RewriteBase /~Jason/hfh/admin/
```

then you may see what you expect. Also you'll may want a clause to not redirect when the File/Directory exists.

Does typing the expected result URL work?

```
/~Jason/hfh/admin/index.php?admin=Collections
```

Edit:

So what happens if you change the whole lot to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~Jason/hfh/admin/index.php?admin=$1 [L]
```

Comment: using RewriteBase /~Jason/hfh/admin/ (and switching the rule back to not include "admin/") still gives me the same "page not found" error in the browser. It's not even trying to do the redirect at all.

Comment: Simeon -- I changed to the RewriteCond lines you suggest -- no change. Same error, even when switching to a totally different browser to control for caching. SO FRUSTRATING

Comment: It sounds like MOD_REWRITE is not running then.

Comment: Repeated from above: Just tested the exact same .htaccess file and directory structure on my webhost server and it worked perfectly. Still not sure why localhost doesn't work, but that's definitely the problem.

Comment: Ok, can you remove the .htaccess from the parent directory, then after that test, then change to single: RewriteRule .* /~Jason/hfh/admin/index.php?admin=collections [L] and check if that has an effect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that would be sending you to the page /~Jason/hfh/index.php?admin=collections, when you want /~Jason/hfh/admin/index.php?admin=collections.

Try changing the rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]*)$ admin/index.php?admin=$1
```

Comment: The problem is that it's not redirecting ANYWHERE. The browser just tells me that /~Jason/hfh/admin/collections cannot be found. If it told me that /~Jason/hfh/index.php?admin=collections could not be found, that would be a different problem, if that makes sense.